# google tensorflow objectdetection Training on the Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset on Google Cloud

Tags: python

I followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md

When I convert to this step:

```
 python object_detection/create_pet_tf_record.py \
    --label_map_path=object_detection/data/pet_label_map.pbtxt \
    --data_dir=`pwd` \
    --output_dir=`pwd`
```

this happened:

```
 File "/work/tensorflow/models/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 36, in _validate_label_map
    raise ValueError('Label map ids should be >= 1.')
ValueError: Label map ids should be >= 1.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your image id probably starts from 0 . The api consider 0 as the background and thus throws the value error. Just increase your id with 1 and it will work like a charm.